# How do I make the select options have a textfield beside them instead of a box?

Tags: webforms

I created a webform that uses dynamic select options generated from a specific content type, which represent objects. I would like to have a text field beside each one to in which the user can input the desired quantity of the object.

I have tried looking this up on Google but to no avail. How should I go about doing this? Is there a module or a specific way by which I can implement this?

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your own custom Form api element looking at select other example
http://drupal.org/project/select_or_other
and the documentation for it form api element is at http://drupal.org/node/1158654